# Can't format BMP image data to 1 bit per pixel in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a black and white bmp image that I need to access 1 pixel at a time. I've found the following code online, but instead of each bit having a value of 1 or 0, its 255 or 0.

```
import Image
img = Image.open(filename)
img = img.convert('1')
pix = img.load()
```

Doing the conversion myself, pixel by pixel, is extremely slow.

can someone tell my why the above methods aren't working?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it like this:

```
img.point(lambda x: bool(x))
```

But why do you need it to be 0/1 (rather than 0/255) in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I need it to be in binary because I'm going to write the data to an LCD screen.

Comment: You don't need lambda here, you should be able to just do `img.point(bool)`.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps numpy is a good solution:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#here, the image will be a numpy array
img = np.array(Image.open(filename)) / 255.
```

If you want to convert it back to image:

```
img = Image.fromarray(img)
```

A little detail: Converting to numpy will flip x and y. Converting back will restore the original positions.