# Python Pillow not producing true 1Bit Monochrome Image

Tags: python, bitmap, grayscale, imaging, monochrome

In python, I'm using the following code to create a 1bpp image:

```
import Image
img = Image.open(filename)
img = img.convert('1')
pix = img.load()
```

I found this code on Stack here: [Can't format BMP image data to 1 bit per pixel in PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067028/cant-format-bmp-image-data-to-1-bit-per-pixel-in-pil)

This code generates what appears to be a monochrome bitmap, but when you look at the data in a hex editor, black is FF is a single pixel and white 00 is a single white pixel. This means the data is 8bpp and not 1bpp like the PIL documentation suggests (https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html?highlight=bit). I've confirmed this to be true because when I replace FF (255) with 80 (128), grey is introduced into the image. With a true monochrome bitmap image, this would not have caused any grey.

This is because a true monochrome image is 1 bit per pixel. Meaning these 2 bytes for example, AA AA, would produce a checker black/white pattern of 16 pixels, while in 8bpp, it would produce two grey pixels.

I'm finding that PIL's 1 bit per pixel mode always generates greyscale. Does anyone know of another library that can help me generate true 1bpp, or know a way to convert the 8bit to 1bit efficiently?

The reason I need this is because I'm attempting to create an image that can be stored on a laser printer. The printer requires 1bpp because laser printers can't actually print grey. It uses dithering to make the appearance of grey.

Comment: PIL is old and un-maintained. Instead of working around its quirks, you might try a newer fork, [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.1.1).

Comment: I was looking at older documentation. I actually do have pillow 3.1.1 installed and this is what I am using. Thanks. Sorry.

Comment: Made edits to reflect newer version